Infinite loop behavior from imagemagick when called from a shell script
I want to post-process pdf documents using imagemagic. I compile the documents themselves through Tex, using Lualatex. After compilation, a script I wrote automatically comes into play, which performs the actions I need and calls imagemagick through \ShellEscape. The problem is that imagemagick does not want to process documents if it receives an incoming file name through a variable. And here's what's strange: it does not return any errors, does not provide any information, and behaves as if it gets into an infinite loop. That is, after launching Lualatex I get a bunch of service information about the document compilation process, and then, when the execution reaches convert, the execution stops. The terminal does not freeze, I can type characters in it, but the task never completes. The task does not load the processor.
If I pass the name of the input file not through a variable, but directly enter it into the command, everything works.
Here's how I run Lualatex from the console:
rm -rf output-Pi/ && lualatex --shell-escape Pi.tex

Here's an example of a broken imagemagick call:
page_array='\"output-Pi/te@mp.com/Main Fu - Pi Lo.pdf[0]\"' &&
convert $(echo $page_array) merge.pdf

Here's an example of a working call:
convert \"output-Pi/te@mp.com/Main Fu - Pi Lo.pdf[0]\" merge.pdf

What do you think about this?
Of course, additional complexity is introduced by the fact that it is necessary to work through three interpreters: the Tex interpreter, which transfers the code to Lua, which transfers the code to Shell. Escaping special characters becomes a headache, but I can’t think of anything better.
tex.sprint("\\ShellEscape{%
    main_dir=\"output-\\jobname\" &&
    email_dir=\"${main_dir}/", ii[1]:gsub(",", ""), "\" &&
    pdf_file_name=\"${email_dir}/Main Fu - Pi Lo\" &&
    mkdir -p $main_dir &&
    mkdir -p $email_dir &&
    lualatex --jobname=\"${pdf_file_name}\" \"\\gdef\\string\\conditionmacro{", t[i], "}\\string\\input\\space\\jobname\" && 
    pdf_file_page=$(identify \"${pdf_file_name}.pdf\" 2>/dev/null | wc -l | tr -d ' ') &&
    page=0 &&
    quote='\"' &&
    while [ $page -lt $pdf_file_page ] ; do page=$(($page + 1)) && page2=$(($page-1)) && echo \"${page2} - ${pdf_file_name}\" &&
    pdf_file_name2=$(echo $pdf_file_name | sed 's/ /\\\\\\ /g') &&
    page_array=\"${page_array}${quote}${pdf_file_name}.pdf[${page2}]\" && page_array=$(echo \"${page_array}${quote} \") ; done &&
    echo \"------------------------------------\" &&
    echo $page_array &&
    echo $SHELL &&
    page_array='\"output-Pi/te@mp.com/Main Fu - Pi Lo.pdf[0]\"' &&
    echo \"convert -density 300 $(echo $page_array) -background  white -density 300 merge.pdf\" &&
    convert $(echo $page_array) merge.pdf &&
    echo \"DONE\"
    }")

Some decisions are dictated by the need to break through 3 interpreters and may seem excessive to you.

Not directly addressing the problem, but echo is risky, as it is doing sometimes unexpected stuff, and you tag the question with bash and shell, so I don't even know whether your echo is the builtin by bash, or the binary in /usr/bin. Also I find it confusing if you name a variable array, when it is not an array. If I see such code, I don't know if the writer was just careless in naming, or whether there is a basic misconception.

$(echo $page_array) should be "$page_array".  The double quotes are necessary to prevent word splitting (which will definitely happen with the example) and pathname expansion (which could happen with the example).

convert \"output-Pi/te@mp.com/Main Fu - Pi Lo.pdf[0]\" merge.pdf won't work if run directly by Bash, or a similar shell.  It passes 6 arguments to convert.  A possible valid command is convert "output-Pi/te@mp.com/Main Fu - Pi Lo.pdf[0]" merge.pdf.

If convert "output-Pi/te@mp.com/Main Fu - Pi Lo.pdf[0]" merge.pdf works then so will page_array="output-Pi/te@mp.com/Main Fu - Pi Lo.pdf[0]"; convert "$page_array" merge.pdf

The variable is an array in the cognitive sense. In the example given it stores one element, but this will not always be the case. Since you ask, I will edit my original post to post most of the script. As for whether the interpreter is Bash or something else, I am not entirely sure myself. The echo $SHELL command gives the output /bin/bash, but in the process of writing the script I found that some features available in Bash do not work. I would not like to completely abandon imagemagick, since in addition to joining several pdfs I need to convert them to images and do some post-processing.

@pjh page_array="output-Pi/te@mp.com/Main Fu - Pi Lo.pdf[0]"; convert "$page_array" merge.pdf really works, but then you need to figure out how to pass an arbitrary number of files to convert. Thanks for your comment about escaping quotes. I have to escape them this way \" because the code is originally written for the Tex interpreter. The code gets into Bash without the slash ".

There are difficulties during development, and there are difficulties during use. By writing all the code in a Tex document, I won't have to worry about anything, I can easily pass it on to someone else and it will work just as well. By putting some of the code in a separate file and thus adding a dependency, I will have to remember to always have this external script available. Considering that I've already spent three days writing this script, maybe I can at least achieve ease of use?

@K J You are right, if pdf is basically a vector file and it has no such thing as density. I use imagemagic to make it non-vector. As I have mentioned before, merging pdf files is not the main task, I need some post processing of the resulting files.

Could you please, give an example of how to get a rasterized version of a multipaged pdf file with a density of 300 dpi from GS?

It works, thanks. This way I can later try to process the images using imagemagick and then reassemble them into one file. Can you tell me another option? How to ask GS to output not images, but one multi-page pdf file at once?

square brackets are not part of the name, they are a way to address a specific page of the file. @ - yes, it can cause problems, but it is very convenient in use and other scripts are already written with the fact of having an email address in the folder name.

is there any way to pass from the command line the names of the files that should be merged into a pdf? Is there a way to just ask GS to rasterize the file and output a single pdf file? Thank you very much for advices.

Thank you for your answers. GS scares me a bit, because I have a lot to learn to use it. Maybe I'll come back to it someday. Luckily, this time, in the answer below I was reminded about the set command, and thus managed to solve the initial problem and IM now does what I want it to do. Thanks again for the advice.

Useless echo. Quotes in the wrong place.
page_array='output-Pi/te@mp.com/Main Fu - Pi Lo.pdf[0]'
convert "$page_array" merge.pdf

Of course, we don't know the context of this shell snippet, and if extra quoting/escaping is required.

I suspect this is what you want
tex.sprint("\\ShellEscape{%
    main_dir=\"output-\\jobname\" &&
    email_dir=\"${main_dir}/", ii[1]:gsub(",", ""), "\" &&
    pdf_file_name=\"${email_dir}/Main Fu - Pi Lo\" &&
    mkdir -p $main_dir &&
    mkdir -p $email_dir &&
    lualatex --jobname=\"${pdf_file_name}\" \"\\gdef\\string\\conditionmacro{", t[i], "}\\string\\input\\space\\jobname\" && 
    set -- \"${pdf_file_name}\".pdf* &&
    echo \"convert -density 300 $* -background  white -density 300 merge.pdf\" &&
    convert \"$@\" merge.pdf &&
    echo \"DONE\"
    }")

I'm assuming that the files you're interested in all start with ${pdf_file_name}.pdf.
I use set -- pattern to store the filenames in the positional parameters, the closest thing to an array that sh has.
Then call convert with the positional parameters. I don't know that tool, so you may need to check if that's correct usage.

Unfortunately, I can't do this, because the page_array variable can contain multiple file names. For example:page_array='\"output-Pi/te@mp.com/Main Fu - Pi Lo.pdf[0]\" \"output-Pi/te@mp.com/Main Fu - Pi Lo.pdf[1]\"'

In this case, using convert $page_array merge.pdf works the same as with echo, that is, it does not work. I chose the option with echo, since I tried to solve the problem with the commands | tr.

page_array="output-Pi/te@mp.com/Main Fu - Pi Lo.pdf[0]"; convert "$page_array" merge.pdf really works, but then you need to figure out how to pass an arbitrary number of files to convert.

We have a winner! set -- actually does a good job and after some code changes I managed to get my code working exactly as it was originally intended. From what I noticed, my question was about the shell's unexpected understanding of spaces and variables. It is not possible to make an array out of a variable if its elements contain a space. Nothing helps, neither escaping spaces with backslashes, nor putting them in quotes -- the shell will still cut the values ​​at spaces. This is very unexpected, since you can escape spaces with backslashes in the command line.

Yes, quotes can be confusing. They are intended to contain your data. Once they are part of your data, they lose their special properties.
